# In a long table, can the text in multirow be shown on two page if the multirow is splitted on two pages?

Tags: longtable, multirow

the code is like this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{c|c}
\multirow{50}{1cm}{abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd }  & test\\
~& test\\
~& test\\
~& test\\
~& test\\
~& test\\
~& test\\
~& test\\
~& test\\
~& test\\
~& test\\
~& test\\
~& test\\
~& test\\
~& test\\
~& test\\
~& test\\
~& test\\
~& test\\
~& test\\
~& test\\
~& test\\
~& test\\
~& test\\
~& test\\
~& test\\
~& test\\
~& test\\
~& test\\
~& test\\
~& test\\
~& test\\
~& test\\
~& test\\
~& test\\
~& test\\
~& test\\
~& test\\
~& test\\
~& test\\
~& test\\
~& test\\
~& test\\
~& test\\
~& test\\
~& test\\
~& test\\
~& test\\
~& test\\
~& test\\
\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

it show this:

[image: what the code shows]

I want the last four lines on page 1 shown on page 2, like this(the picture is done without multirow, but because the real problem is more complex, I have to use multirow.):

[image: the target picture]

How to do it?

Comment: longtable only supports splitting between rows it never splits a cell of the table.

Comment: got it, I will try other method, thanks!